# What is the deployment blueprint of an application in cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am confused if should be Manifest or Buildpack or neither of these. Please suggest your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

So I would say thinking of things as exclusive options is incorrect. A manifest dictates which buildpack to use.

The advantage of a manifest is it allows a developer to commit the proper configuration with the source code. This means that configuration is versioned along with source code.

So my opinion is to use both.

Comment: But if we need to select one would it be buildpack ?

Comment: @Sam when deploying to cloud foundry you have to use a buildpack.

Comment: Not technically, you can deploy `cf push` docker containers which don't use buildpacks. I agree with the rest of what you're saying though. It's not either/or. You almost always use a buildpack. The either/or question is do you use a manifest or do you specify options as command line arguments to `cf push`. The application manifest is just another way to tell `cf push` how to deploy your app.

Comment: Only for foundations that allow that, but you're right of course.